# 20" long remote plastic breaker handle lever

Tags: electrical-panel

Does anyone know what kind of plastic lever that is about 20" long that can turn off or on a breaker handle so in case the breaker arc flashed, the fingers won't be injured? The following happened in 2015 where the electrician fingers were injured when the breaker arc flashed.

[image]

So even though I already ordered a $500 arc flash suit, it still can't protect the hands because the incident energy there is too powerful even with gloves (due to melting slags, etc.) Hence want to use long remote plastic lever to turn it off or on. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some more photos, showing the area surrounding that switch? - There are probably some other precautions you should take beyond using a stick to throw the switch, e.g. removing the flammable cardboard.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such device for that type of breaker. It is DESIGNED to be mounted into what's called a "dead front" panel in which only the handle sticks through. That would have prevented the collateral damage in the event of an arc flash due to breaker failure. Someone has built something with a breaker that was not intended to be used in that manner, so there is no support for off-book usage.

***PROPERLY designed Arc Flash protection suits*** will prevent injury in an arc flash event taking place with doors open, a "40cal" suit ***and gloves*** would likely be more than adequate for the level of incident energy that can be associated with that series of breaker (10kAIC). But a "plastic handle" would not really protect anyone unless it was long enough to put them outside of the Blast Radius which I think would be 48" (I'm not going to look it up for you...)

There are different designs of Molded case Circuit Breakers that can be used and operated with the doors completely closed and have an external operating handle. You may want to rethink what you are using this for in that respect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell exactly how much danger you are in, but it's a lot. The $500 would be better spent hiring a licensed professional to bring that installation up to code.

Judging from your incomplete yet terrifying description and photograph, even *sleeping* in the flash suit is not going to save your life. Get somebody in who knows what he is doing, and let him solve your electrical service problems in a safe and legal manner.

EDIT: I have been told that where you are, you can't easily hire a competent professional and must take the responsibility to keep yourself safe.

If the breaker comes from a reputable manufacturer and is large enough to handle the load, it should be safe to throw the switch handle without extra safety precautions.

If you're worried, though, you could cut a notch in a hardwood stick and use it to keep your hand away from the breaker. I made a thing like this to keep my hands away from my oven rack:

[image: stick]

If you're not going to be throwing the breaker every day, you don't need anything more complex than this. If you *are* going to be throwing the breaker every day, you will soon learn that it doesn't flash or spark when you do.

Judging from the photograph, I'd say that the flash damage occurred when the contractor tried to connect the live wires while the breaker was switched on. The instant he touched the wire to the terminal, all the loads on the circuit began drawing power, causing the spark.

Turning the breaker off even when working on the live wires upstream is a good idea because that not only prevents the flash damage shown in your photo, but avoids a possible shock from current flowing through the loads and energizing the other breaker terminal screw even before it is connected.

Most likely your contractor didn't do this and then tried to blame his injury on the breaker.

Comment: Do keep in mind that the OP is in the Philippines, so there may be a shortage of people who truly know what they are doing in that locale...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I was afraid of something like that. We'll have to get more information from the OP.

Comment: It occured in 2015 when contractor electrician was landing the live wire to the breaker at commercial bldg.  We had already replaced the breaker (and removed the cardboard) that year. And no incidence since then. I just realized it was arc flash after Harper told me to be careful with arc flash. So to be sure. I will turn on or off any breakers with plastic lever at minimum 18" which is how PPE should be used. At home..no problem with arc flash bec incident energy is calculated to be low.

Comment: I can see that since you can't easily hire a competent professional, my advice is inappropriate and not helpful. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Good advice, when the lineman was fixing our neutral and the neighbor's hot, he had me shut all the main breakers off, which fortunately were outside. Good thing he sent me, because the neighbor had 2 main breakers.

Comment: What really happened was the electrician lowered the live wire to the breaker that was OFF without any load connected. But a cooper strand touched the chassis which was grounded (as all commercial panels are except residential). So it caused a 208v open delta high leg arc flash between it and chassis which blew a hole in back the chassis as well as splatter the wall. The arc flash caused a rat size 2nd degree burn in the electrician arm too. It happened in 2015. But I didn't know it was arc flash until Harper warned me my residential panel may arc flash (it won't bec incident energy is low)

Comment: Anyway Harper, as I result of your arc flash comment of my home original panel rewiring where the wires were crisscrossing the front and you warnt arc flash can ignite the cabinet..I spent nearly two month studying it at depth, asking many questions from arc flash experts and even bought a $500 12cal/cm2 PPE just to turn on or off the office breaker and to use the faceshield/helmet at home in case it is needed. Your words have power Harper, simply saying two words "arc flash" caused me so much actions, etc. Here is my $500 arc flash attire https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img923/3729/k5KMq0.jpg